# Unable to run C on VScode macOS

Tags: c, macos

I have been trying to run C on VScode but it keeps giving me the same error. I have brew and gcc installed on my mac. I have installed the C and Code Runner extension on VScode as well. Keeps giving me this error:

```
In file included from hello.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:68:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from hello.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from hello.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
In file included from hello.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
In file included from hello.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from hello.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:32:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_va_list'
typedef __darwin_va_list va_list;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1
Set the GCC Environment Variables properly.

Option 2
Delete the Setup(VSCode) completely and setup it again properly.

Prefer using only Visual Studio Code editor don't use the whole VisualStudio for this you need to setup properly.